# In R package Xaringan, unable to render with infinite moon reader

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, xaringan

Using the `R` package `xaringan`, I was trying to create a new presentation in `RStudio`. I wanted to use the very useful feature `inifinite moon reader` to get live preview of my tweaking of the presentation.  While worked nicely previously, currently for me the presentation is not rendering anymore.  What changed in between is probably regular updates in software, operating system and R packages.

Now whenever I press the `infinite moon reader` addin in `RStudio`, it spits the error as shown in the image.  But when I press the `knit to moonreader` button in `RStudio` it renders the document just fine but there is not live preview.

I tried to run `R` in a console and then used the `inf_mr()` function to render the document. It spits out the same error. But `rmarkdown::render()` function works just fine but again with no live preview.    I  searched for this error but I do not seem to find anything as such related to `xaringan` package in `R`.   Then I ran a more generalized search and found that the error statement most often comes in the case of `XML` parsing.  I updated the `XML` and `XML2` packages in `R` but with no luck. Then I updated and upgraded my Arch Linux also to no avail.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#>  os       Arch Linux                  
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Asia/Dhaka                  
#>  date     2019-08-13                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  backports     1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  callr         2.0.4   2018-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  curl          3.3     2019-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  devtools      2.0.2   2019-04-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  digest        0.6.20  2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  fs            1.3.1   2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  httr          1.4.0   2018-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  knitr         1.24    2019-08-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  mime          0.7     2019-06-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  nvimcom     * 0.9-75  2019-08-13 [1] local         
#>  pkgbuild      1.0.3   2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  png           0.1-7   2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  processx      3.2.0   2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  ps            1.1.0   2018-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.2   2019-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  remotes       2.0.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  rlang         0.4.0   2019-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  rmarkdown     1.14    2019-07-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  stringi       1.4.3   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  testthat      2.1.1   2019-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  usethis       1.5.1   2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  xfun          0.8     2019-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  xml2          1.2.2   2019-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#> 
#> [1] /home/arch/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6
#> [2] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Comment: The issue has been reported once at https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/197. I suggest you use an external browser to view the slides.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this same error it was because I had the `.Rmd` file for the presentation open in a separate window. Once I returned it to the main window, `xaringan::inf_mr()` displayed the presentation in the Viewer tab with no problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a `separate window`? Is it a separate window in Rstudio or browser or something else?